# Asking about C# Property in VS 2017

Tags: c#, properties

```
public override Type PropertyType
{
     get
     {
          return this.propertydescriptor.PropertyType;
     }
}
```

from above I can change it like below? it working same?

```
public override Type PropertyType => propertydescriptor.PropertyType;
```

Comment: running it in some test code should give you an answer

Comment: They are exactly the same. You can check: https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmKAmCBhJBvJEhEAlgHYAuEpEAvBACwKJEQFGokUQAKATgPYAHAKa9yAT2gR8zFkQDmwyjLmqoAdipM1EAL5tC+2YQNQ0ZSnyGiJmGgD4tppLqA